# Hide div using jquery without parent div

Tags: jquery, html, hide

When i click on the button will hide all the `<div.main>` (each with 6  will hide at the same time).

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <button>Hide</button><br />
        <div class="main"><img src="http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs46/f/2009/230/a/4/Spongebob_10_150x150_PNG_by_somemilk.png" /></div>
        <div class="main"><img src="http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs46/f/2009/230/a/4/Spongebob_10_150x150_PNG_by_somemilk.png" /></div>
        <div class="main"><img src="http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs46/f/2009/230/a/4/Spongebob_10_150x150_PNG_by_somemilk.png" /></div>
        <div class="main"><img src="http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs46/f/2009/230/a/4/Spongebob_10_150x150_PNG_by_somemilk.png" /></div>
        <div class="main"><img src="http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs46/f/2009/230/a/4/Spongebob_10_150x150_PNG_by_somemilk.png" /></div>
        <div class="main"><img src="http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs46/f/2009/230/a/4/Spongebob_10_150x150_PNG_by_somemilk.png" /></div>
        <div class="main"><img src="http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs46/f/2009/230/a/4/Spongebob_10_150x150_PNG_by_somemilk.png" /></div>
        <div class="main"><img src="http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs46/f/2009/230/a/4/Spongebob_10_150x150_PNG_by_somemilk.png" /></div>
        <div class="main"><img src="http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs46/f/2009/230/a/4/Spongebob_10_150x150_PNG_by_somemilk.png" /></div>
        <div class="main"><img src="http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs46/f/2009/230/a/4/Spongebob_10_150x150_PNG_by_somemilk.png" /></div>
        <div class="main"><img src="http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs46/f/2009/230/a/4/Spongebob_10_150x150_PNG_by_somemilk.png" /></div>
        <div class="main"><img src="http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs46/f/2009/230/a/4/Spongebob_10_150x150_PNG_by_somemilk.png" /></div>
        <div class="main"><img src="http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs46/f/2009/230/a/4/Spongebob_10_150x150_PNG_by_somemilk.png" /></div>
        <div class="main"><img src="http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs46/f/2009/230/a/4/Spongebob_10_150x150_PNG_by_somemilk.png" /></div>
        <div class="main"><img src="http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs46/f/2009/230/a/4/Spongebob_10_150x150_PNG_by_somemilk.png" /></div>
        <div class="main"><img src="http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs46/f/2009/230/a/4/Spongebob_10_150x150_PNG_by_somemilk.png" /></div>
        <div class="main"><img src="http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs46/f/2009/230/a/4/Spongebob_10_150x150_PNG_by_somemilk.png" /></div>
        <div class="main"><img src="http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs46/f/2009/230/a/4/Spongebob_10_150x150_PNG_by_somemilk.png" /></div>
        <div class="main"><img src="http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs46/f/2009/230/a/4/Spongebob_10_150x150_PNG_by_somemilk.png" /></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 900px;
}
.main {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XGkAt/

How to get there?

Comment: Have you tried any jquery yet?

Comment: Get where, here -> http://jsfiddle.net/XGkAt/2/. ....

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('div.main').hide();
});
```

You should probably add an ID or a class to your button. Right now this will fire ANYTIME a `button` is clicked.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XGkAt/1/

Comment: BUT, this would apply a listener to **any** button on the page, meaning if you clicked a button, the div would be hidden. This answer is correct, strictly speaking, but not very practical. Put an id on the button (and the target div, for that matter), then use `$("#myButtonId")` -- being explicit is always a good approach.

Comment: In this case you could select it with `$(".container button")`

Comment: This will fail in case there are more HTML blocks like this one. Clicking one of the buttons will also hide the other div.main outside of this block.

Comment: @Virus721 That may be the goal, though. In fact, it appears to be.

Comment: @Virus721 -- What do you mean outside this block? I see all these `div.main` under one container?

Comment: @tymeJV He's saying that if there is some other block on the page, totally unrelated to this one, your use of `$("div.main").hide();` will clobber them all. A better approach might be to use the parent of the event target (`$(this).parent().find('.main').hide();`), as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/XGkAt/3/

Comment: @Chris -- Ahh gotcha, I thought this was the all the content there would be, I'll edit the answer, give me a min.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(your button).on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().children('div.main').hide();
});
```

Could maybe work.

Answer (score 0):

6 is mentioned in the question. If you're wanting to delete them six at a time, the following should do what you're after (in an admittedly crude way):

```
$(".container button").click(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        $("div.main:visible").first().hide(); 
    }
});
```

You will obviously need jQuery, which wasn't included in your original jsFiddle.